# Proof of the monotonicity of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I do not know how to solve this problem, could someone help me?

Show that if

$$0 < c < d$$

Then $$(c^n + d^n)^{1/n}$$ is monotonic.

I already now it is decreasing but when I try to prove $a(n+1) < a(n)$, something goes wrong.

Comment: i solved it by working backwards ,that is,upwards from the bottom line.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c/d=e.$ We have $0<e<1$.So for any real $n \ge 1$ we have $$1+e^n>1+e^{n+1}.$$ $$(1+e^n)^{(n+1)/n}>1+e^{n+1}.$$ $$(1+e^n)^{1/n}>(1+e^{n+1})^{1/(n+1)}.$$ $$d(1+e^n)^{1/n}>d(1+e^{n+1})^{1/(n+1)}.$$ $$(d^n+(d e)^n)^{1/n}>(d^{n+1}+(de)^{n+1})^{1/(n+1)}.$$  $$(d^n+c^n)^{1/n}>(d^{n+1}+c^{n+1})^{1/(n+1)}.$$